# "Bolt-On companies"

Tags: meaning

I have to translate the plenary session's minutes of a company related to cars and automotive manufacture and this appears during the intervention of the CFO:

"2017 H2 was clearly showing an acceleration of the goals of the company. We’re close to 13% growth on organic basis, meaning excluding exchange rate and differences of scope, including the consolidation of new companies, or Bolt-On companies."

Can you explain to me what is a **Bolt-On company**? I have only found "bolt-on acquisitions" and it has not helped me.

Than you so much.

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bolt-on) **bolt-on** *- added to a main product, service, or plan as a smaller, extra part or feature, especially in business* Example usage: *Davidow said the business would continue to make **bolt-on acquisitions.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEFINITION of 'Tuck-In Acquisition** aka a **bolt on company**  [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tuckinacquisition.asp)

A tuck-in acquisition involves a larger company completely absorbing another, usually smaller, company and completely integrating it into the acquirer's platform. Tuck-in acquisitions are usually executed in order to grow the acquiring company's market share or resource base. A tuck-in acquisition is sometimes referred to as a "**bolt-on acquisition**."